# How is this thing done (website example): making animated logo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

How is [this site's](http://madebyfieldwork.com/) logo was made? Is it Javascript? Could somebody advice what to google/read to be able to do something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done with **svg**. If you inspect the site you can see they use a js library named **Snap.svg**. The best way to learn how a web site is done is by using browser's dev tools. Regards.